# Як правильно перекласти "aftercare" в значенні "продлёнка"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian, фразеологізми

Чи існує в українській мові ідіома для перекладу слова *продлёнка* в значенні додаткові заняття?

Мені здається, що найближчий перевод до слова *продлевать* в такому контексті буде *утривалювати*. Але від слова *утривалювати* я не можу утворити ніякого слушного переводу для ідіоми *продлёнка*.

Я знаю про існування фразеологізму *група продовженого дня* але цікавить, чи існує якесь стале скорочення?

Comment: aftercare - двома словами 'після-' або 'понад-' терміновий догляд або турбота. 

у випадку дітей у садочку особисто я б виразив це як 'довгий день' або 'на вечір'. наприклад 'лишили малого на довгий день' або 'сьогодні лишимо дітей на вечір та сходимо нарешті у кіно'

Comment: Це не є повноцінною відповіддю, але у медицині використовується термін [**післядогляд**](http://www.babor.lviv.ua/poslugy/kosmetologiya-uk/chistka/). Особисто мені — подобається. А в освіті я чув лише жахливу кальку «продльонка», навіть серед вчителів.

Comment: @Yola може й добре, але занадто суб'єктивно і не підходить під `сталий вираз`

Comment: Ще можна назвати *додатковими* заняттями. Тобто можна відштовхуватись від слова *додатково*. Наприклад, `Дитина залишилась в школі на додаткові.`

Comment: Ще варіанти: *післяшкола, післяклас, післякласи.*

Comment: Пропоную винести варіанти з коментів у відповіді, щоб Володимир зміг потім обрати якийсь.
Як на мене, то найкраще - «післяшкола/післяклас» від Yola
Але і «післядогляд» від @bytebuster теж як варіант нічого

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для перекладу *aftercare* у значенні додаткові заняття (якщо мова йде про освітній заклад) я б використав словосполучення *післяурочна освіта/діяльність*, *післяурочне дозвілля/виховання*, *післяурочні заняття/години*, *післяурочний догляд*. Зрозуміло, що такий переклад звужує і уточнює оригінальне значення. Можливо, підійде і слово «[довчання](http://sum.in.ua/s/dovchannja)».

Знову ж таки, залишається словосполучення *подовжений/продовжений день* (“extended day”), яке прийшло до нас [з радянської доби і є калькою російської](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine24-21.pdf). Воно виглядає застарілим, але є усталеним і використовується у документах. Здається, існує [суперечність](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/index.php?showtopic=1246) як правильно: «продовжений» чи «[подовжений](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/156.htm)» день. Я більше схиляюсь до думки [подовжений](http://chak-chy-pravylno-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/p#podovzhenyi) (у часі). Тоді можна сказати *подовжене навчання*.

Прямого еквівалента до російського неологізму «продленка» в українській мові немає. Найближчим, напевне, буде «*вечірка*» – вечірня школа, але зараз це слово має іншу суть. В будь-якому разі, не варто створювати переклади англійських термінів, взявши за основу російські аналоги.

Comment: Дякую. `післяурочний догляд` мені подобається набагато більше ніж `група продовженого дня`

Answer (score 5):

[ГПД](http://profosvitamk.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=338:2013-10-21-11-00-11&catid=7:2011-06-22-11-10-48&Itemid=7) (ГеПеДе) - група подовженого дня. Я там був.

Answer (score 3):

Ось тут, на [Словотворі](http://slovotvir.org.ua) є варіант *подовжня*

[image]

**Відредаговано:**
Після коментаря @VolodymyrFrolov і консультації з [r2u](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8F&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on), я дійшов висновку, що *подовжня* - невдалий переклад. Краще звернутись до одного з перекладів наведених у коментарях до запитання.

Comment: Будь ласка, додавайте ключові положення із прив'язаної статті прямо у вашу відповідь. Наразі тут присутній лише знімок екрану, який недоступний для людей, що користуються VoiceOver

Comment: Слово "подовжня" перекладається як "продольная" або "продолговатая". Не думаю, що це саме те, що мається на увазі. Також не думаю, що мене зрозуміють, якщо я буду це слово використовувати.

Answer (score 2):

Перш за все, *aftercare* означає *the care of people after they have left a hospital or prison*, тобто догляд  за одужуючими або людиною, що щойно вийшла на волю.

[Переклади](http://translate.academic.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0/ru/en/1) слова *продленка* на англійську мову:

1. General subject: homework club (в школі - Великобрит., HC), pre-school club (приблизний аналог), after-school club
2. American English: after-school child-care

Щодо українського аналога слова *продленка*, то мені більше всього подобається варіант

**додаткове заняття**

як це вказано у автора посту і в деяких коментарях.

Comment: Гадаю, у контексті можна вживати просто **додаткове**, без заняття.

Comment: Стосовно `aftercare`, таке значення є одним із можливих переводів, але не єдиним можливим. Американці в повсякденному житті цим словом називають саме `післяурочний догляд` - різноманітні гуртки, позашкільне навчання тощо.